# Object Property method and have the good inference of the function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to type properly for Object method and have the good inference of the functions.

```
  const P = <T,>(x: T) => ({ "foo": (R: Function) => R(x) });

  const f = (a: number) => a + 1;
  const g = (a: number) => a.toString();

  const p1 = f(5); //const p1: number         // good
  const p2 = g(5); //const p2: string         // good

  const q1 = P(5)['foo'](f); //const q1: any   // bad
  const q2 = P(5)['foo'](g); //const q2: any   // bad

  console.log(q1);
  console.log(q2);
```

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATDGHsDsGcBdgArALzADwBUA0A+AFAB4BcwGAlCjsHgN7ABEAZuOPSXgEokBiArpKFgBLKBWRUOhCgF8yAbgBQCkBBjxGKagEMSkXgFsARgFMATmKpbgAamABGRSqhxgAc014dwPUbMXgWgB0sOAAyrCmQpCuePJKTmrAAA52mox4AKzywAD0OaouKboGJqYg5RV5biwAJspgzvBJAEyaMVlyufmNyc0kcJHRFcNVrrXxDYkAjqmoCJlkANoA5MzgywC6eIzZeQXwMyRakACe5VWGWnUJLlOtcwsra5t4rrvd030Bp+c5wJd1eoFcAAG2MgRB4BiMziN1B4Mh0Oa8iAA)

Any ideas? Thanks!

```js
"use strict";
const P = (x) => ({ "foo": (R) => R(x) });

const f = (a) => a + 1;
const g = (a) => a.toString();

const p1 = f(5); //const p1: number         // good
const p2 = g(5); //const p2: string         // good

const q1 = P(5)['foo'](f); //const q1: any   // bad
const q2 = P(5)['foo'](g); //const q2: any   // bad

console.log(q1);
console.log(q2);
```

Comment: TypeScript language inference ability limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [the `Function` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function) is probably a bad idea; it represents an *untyped function* which accepts any parameters whatsoever and returns the unsafe [`any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  That means `P` is inferred to have the following type:

```
const P = <T,>(x: T) => ({ "foo": (R: Function) => R(x) });
/* const P: <T>(x: T) => {
  foo: (R: Function) => any;
} */
```

And so `P(x).foo(y)` will always return a value of type `any` for all `x` and `y`. Oops.

---

If you want the compiler to keep track of both the type of `x` and the return type of `R` you will need to make the returned function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and give `R` an appropriate [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions), like this:

```
const P = <T,>(x: T) => ({ "foo": <U,>(R: (x: T) => U) => R(x) });
```

Now it should work as desired:

```
const q1 = P(5)['foo'](f);
//const q1: number
console.log(q1.toFixed(2)) // "6.00"
const q2 = P(5)['foo'](g);
//const q2: string
console.log(q2.repeat(2)) // "55"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4Cgkl4B7YKAFyQAUkBeJAHgBUAaAPgAoAPALiWYBKeuySdcSAEQAzEiUn9OAJX4AxAK7B4FDGWF1RSnsIC+ggNyEkAegBUxMpRr8WXPgP2iCRIrJKKVJA0tHT0RJBBgAE9LIhMkW2t8E3x8UnIqWgYWDh5+IXDxKT8FJgBVXMC8j3CyzyQjblMLVPSnaXoxEH5gdTAAIwg0epAkAGokAEZLNqocBk5upF6BoZGAOgoSAGUKTGAsTha0xyoAR0nO6k4AVkEAbQByP0eAXU5pFutrWaQLnr6gzQJ3IJAANhB1mCSIcLpsSKoMNwIAATTgAJkEwm+UgAbOsAAwEyQgpxndFXW4PZ5yN6cLBfH6nP7o-iUfZYUngyHQ2Ho9ZoCAwCAgCgYrE2axSG43EmpIA)

Comment: I made a spin-off Question: [TypeScript error 2345 while redefining Object Property method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69777432/typescript-error-2345-while-redefining-object-property-method),  based on your answer. See if you have a time. Thanks.